# How can I install pip3 packages to a private instance?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a python script running in a instance inside a private subnet, that script requires external libraries such as boto3. I can't install them using something like `pip3 install boto3` because private instances don't have access to the internet. How can I do this?

Comment: Generally the private instances still have outgoing internet access for exactly this type of reason (along with operating system updates).  Do you have a NAT gateway installed?

Comment: How do you connect to the instance to access the command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to install everything offline, you can create a list of required packages with `pip download` install each of them individually with pip install <package_name.whl>:

1.Use venv on internet-connected machine to isolate requirements from your system setup

```
mkdir ~/package-requirements
python3 -m venv ~/package-requirements
source ~/package-requirements/bin/activate
```

2.Download desired package and all requirements as `.whl` files:

```
pip3 download pandas
```

3. Copy all `.whl` files from your work directory to target machine and install each of them individually:

   pip3 install numpy-1.21.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl

   pip3 install pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

   pip3 install six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

   pip3 install python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

   pip3 install pandas-1.3.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

Comment: Because many wheels are already platform-dependent, might as well just create a tar achive of the venv. The source machine will need to be the same OS.

Comment: If your platform is different than target, you can specify it with --platform or use pip freeze to get the list of required packages and download them off github as source using version tags or releases and install with pip3 install <dir>.